# What could be wrong with my hp M2N78-LA motherboard?

Tags: motherboard, hardware-failure, heatsink

Lately my computer would freeze for no apparent reason after 5 or 6 minutes after power on. I started suspecting a virus. So I restored my previously unaffected OS Window 7 Image. Stopped processes one after another. Changed the system Hard Drive. Disconnected every other peripherals other than strictly needed HD and monitor. The behavior is strange. The mouse suddenly stop responding, idem for the keyboard. The computer completely stop responding to any peripherals. Disconnecting or connecting USB devices would not react in anyway. The only way to revive the computer is to turn the power down completely and restart from scratch. And then, 5 minutes later it freezes again. Yet, I could reboot it and run for 5 minutes.

What could be wrong with my hp M2N78-LA motherboard ?

Answer (score 1):

I suddenly suspected that this behavior strangely resemble to a thermal problem for it is so timely. It's just as if 5 minutes later something get too hot and stop working. I checked the microprocessor fan, it was OK. Then I accidentally put my fingers on the MCP78OV  Nvidia Video processor heat sink and almost got a burn. This was way too hot to be normal I suspected.

Further investigation lead me to find that the double sided tape that is utilized as a thermal contact between the MCP78OV processor and the Heat sink was totally dry and brittle. I concluded that the thermal contact was no more adequate and proceeded to scrape all the remaining adhesive and use some good quality thermal conductive electronic paste. Put back the heat sink radiator and added a miniature 12vdc heat sink fan as an extra heat re-circulation device. The temperature sink is now kept at a relatively cold 42 degree Celsius. And the problem is gone completely. For those who find a similar problem with their old motherboard it is my opinion that this problem is most probably common. These cheap thermal adhesive tapes are OK for some time but at such high temperature they age and tend to become insulator rather than heat conductors. Don't scrap you motherboard before you investigate that possibility.
Hope this help. Cheers